# How can I get the list of pretrained large language models?

Tags: nlp, language-model, finetuning, llm

Is there any place I can get the list of pre-trained large language models in a neat way? Despite the most common ones like gpt, BARD, llama2, which llm do you suggest that can be used for RAG and fine-tuning? Especially I am looking forward multilingual models.

Comment: Hugging face is a particularly good starting place, but there are probably others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful resources:-

i. [Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/)

ii. [Awesome-LLM: a curated list of Large Language Model](https://github.com/Hannibal046/Awesome-LLM)

iii. [A list of open LLMs available for commercial use.](https://github.com/eugeneyan/open-llms)

iv. [A curated list for Efficient Large Language Models](https://github.com/horseee/Awesome-Efficient-LLM)

v. [A curated list of Large Language Model (LLM) Interpretability resources.](https://github.com/JShollaj/awesome-llm-interpretability)

vi [A Curated List of Language Models in Scientific Domains](https://github.com/yuzhimanhua/Awesome-Scientific-Language-Models)

vii. [A curated list of awesome LLMs & deep learning strategies & tools in financial market.](https://github.com/georgezouq/awesome-ai-in-finance)

vii. [Must-read Papers on pre-trained language models.](https://github.com/thunlp/PLMpapers)

Some of these resources cater to specific aspects of working with Large Language Models. Note the list is not exhaustive and there might be other resources available.